# How does TBATS work?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, references, tbats

How Does TBATS Work? Or let me know where to find a good high level description of how TBATS fits a model to complex seasonal data.  For example data that has a year, month, day, hour seasonal pattern?  I'm looking for something similar to what you can find for `auto.arima` at https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7.  I've been working with TBATS for a year, and read the relevant paper but I'm having a hard time explaining it.

Comment: When you say *high level description*, do you mean detailed and technical or intuitive and "big picture"? Sorry, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @RichardHardy  Thanks for getting back to me, I mean big picture.